# Remove %2F from URLs with mod_rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, clean-urls

I would like to remove the '%252F' from my dynamically created URLs.
I have a php-file that creates links with a `%2F` instead of `/`.
The links are then represented in the URL-Bar as `%252F` instead of `/` which leads to some problems.
What I'm trying to achieve with a .htaccess-file is to redirect all `%2F` to `/` or rename all `%252F` to `/` since I can't change the php-code creating the links.

**This is my .htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine on
Options +SymlinksIfOwnerMatch
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} subdomain.mydomain.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.*)/style.css [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.*)/script.js [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.*)/logo.png
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.mydomain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD}  !=POST
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^/]+/)*index\.php\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(([^/]+/)*)index\.php$ http://subdomain.mydomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /([^\ \?]*)([^\ \?]*)%2f(\?.*)?\  [NC]
RewriteRule !^/ /%1/%2 [QSA]

RewriteRule ^(/.+)%2f(.*)$ $1/$2 [NC,QSA]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+index\.php\?dir=([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?dir=/$1 [L]
```

I can't get it to work, maybe someone else can help me with this.
Thank you very much!

Comment: Why not fix the broken PHP script instead?

Answer (score 0):

The lines:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /([^\ \?]*)([^\ \?]*)%2f(\?.*)?\  [NC]
RewriteRule !^/ /%1/%2 [QSA]

RewriteRule ^(/.+)%2f(.*)$ $1/$2 [NC,QSA]
```

Need to have the leading slash removed. URI's sent through rules in htaccess files have the leading slash stripped off:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /([^\ \?]*)([^\ \?]*)%2f(\?.*)?\  [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2 [QSA]

RewriteRule ^(.+)%2f(.*)$ $1/$2 [NC,QSA,L]
```

Not sure what the `RewriteRule !^/ /%1/%2 [QSA]` line is supposed to do, it looks like you're stripping out a trailing slash?

Comment: I found the rule you are reffering to here: [link](http://forum.modrewrite.com/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=6827)  

But neither of the rules seems to change anything.  
The following rule gets me rid of the first %252F:

`RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+index\.php\?dir=%2F([^\s]+) [NC]  

RewriteRule ^ %1? [R=301,L]`

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get rid of the first `%252F` in the URL and the problem of "stacking" slashes:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD}  !=POST
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^/]+/)*index\.php\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(([^/]+/)*)index\.php$ http://subdomain.mydomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+index\.php\?dir=%2F([^\s]+) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+index\.php\?dir=([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?dir=/$1 [L]
```

I still have the problem of having `%252F` in my URLs though.